# Calculate a form field, based on the previous forms in the formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an inline formset, attached to a main form, and I'm trying to do some updates to a formset form field:

So I inherit from `BaseInlineFormSet`.

I know I can do the validation at the form level using `clean_field`, but I need to number if the `teck` field was completed.

Basically each form of the formset depends if the field 'teck' was completed on previous forms.

```
class BaseTeckInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        idx = 0
        for form in self.forms:
                if form.cleaned_data['teck']:
                ...... form.cleaned_data['key'] = idx
                idx = 1
```

but even if I change here, the key somewhere it fails, is reinstantiated, because I get:

null value in column "key" violates not-null constraint